# Find the minimum of the function

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve a problem that is as follows:

Find the minimum value of $$ (a+b+c+d+e)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}\right) ,\qquad a,b,c,d,e>0.$$
I have done this as :
\begin{align*}
& (a+b+c+d+e)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}\right)\\
= & \left(5+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{a}{d}+\frac{d}{a}+\frac{a}{e}+\frac{e}{a}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{d}{b}+\frac{b}{e}+\frac{e}{b}+\cdots\right)\\
\ge & 5+2\times 4+2\times 3 +2\times 2+2\times 1\\
= &25
\end{align*}
Could you please tell me whether I'm correct or not?

Comment: I think you need to reverse the inequality. First of all, because this one is not true - and secondly, because if you want to find a minimum, you need to prove that the expression is not *greater* than some particular value.

Comment: @Justpassingby a minimum is a value that the function takes, which the function is never _less_ than.

Comment: yeah thanks for the correction.

Comment: @kag My comment did not make sense but the OP got the hint and corrected the inequality

Answer (score 2):

You can get there easier by setting $a = b = c = d = e = n$:

$$ (a+b+c+d+e)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{e}\right) $$

$$ = (n+n+n+n+n)\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\right) $$

$$ = (5n)\left(\frac{5}{n}\right) = 25$$

Answer (score 0):

For positive $a,b$ we have $a/b+b/a=(\sqrt {a/b}-\sqrt {b/a})^2+2\geq 2.$ In the expansion  you have $\binom {5}{2}=10$ terms of this type. Add this to the $5$ and you have a minimum of $5+10.2=25$ with the minimum attained only when $a=b=c=d=e.$ This generalizes to any number $n$ of variables because $n+2.\binom {n}{2}=n^2.$ There is a name for this inequality, but I have forgotten it.